# Search Filter by Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to search list of cards that contain products using Javascript. The aim is to only show the results that contain the name of the product. I'm not sure if my approach is correct or not but I've been following tutorials online and all seem to only show list search using the "ul" tags. Is it a requirement?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("card-content");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div class="columns is-multiline" id="myUL">
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div class="card has-text-centered">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>$100</p>
        <p class="hippo">Playstation 5</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
        </p>
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div class="card has-text-centered">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>$250</p>
        <p class="hippo">Xbox</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
        </p>
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure why my code above isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should be ul.getElementsByClassName instead of ul.getElementsByTagName

Comment: `li = ul.querySelectorAll(".card-content");` return 0 `lenght` use instead `querySelectorAll / getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing almost fine.  Here is the working version.  I fixed three parts.

- you searched 'card-content' tag by calling `ul.getElementsByTagName("card-content")`.  It should search the class name `.card-content`.
- you tried to get the text content of the first p element.  The first p element contains the price.  Since the product name is tagged with the `hippo` class, I changed to search `p.hippo` with `querySelector()` method.
- if you want to hide the whole div section, you can get two parents above the `.card-content` node and set its `display` to none.

```
    function myFunction () {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.querySelectorAll(".card-content");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].querySelector("p.hippo");
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

Another (better) way to hide the whole surrounding `div` is that you search that `div` first.  And then obtain the product name within it.  Since you have a reference to the surrounding `div` you don't have to go up the parent node.

Here is the solution.  I also modified the code in the recomended style such as minimizing the use of local variables, using `const` for immutable data, avoiding `for` loop using counter variables.  This is just the matter of the taste so it is not mandatory.

```
  function myFunction2 () {
      const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      document.querySelectorAll("div.is-one-fifth").forEach(div => {
        const product = div.querySelector("p.hippo");
        const productName = product.textContent || product.innerText;
        if (productName.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
          div.style.display = "";
        else
          div.style.display = "none";
      });
    }
```

Here is the complete code that you can run and test.  I added borders to the surrounding `div`, so you can make sure that the whole `div` section is invisible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    input {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .is-one-fifth {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid green;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .card {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    function myFunction2 () {
      const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      document.querySelectorAll("div.is-one-fifth").forEach(div => {
        const product = div.querySelector("p.hippo");
        const productName = product.textContent || product.innerText;
        if (productName.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
          div.style.display = "";
        else
          div.style.display = "none";
      });
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <div class="columns is-multiline" id="myUL">
    <div class="column is-one-fifth">
      <div class="card has-text-centered">
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>$100</p>
          <p class="hippo">Playstation 5</p>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
          <p class="card-footer-item">
            <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
          </p>
          <p class="card-footer-item">
            <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
          </p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column is-one-fifth">
      <div class="card has-text-centered">
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>$250</p>
          <p class="hippo">Xbox</p>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
          <p class="card-footer-item">
            <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
          </p>
          <p class="card-footer-item">
            <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
          </p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How would I modify the javascript to not show "View" or "Add to Cart" to anything other than the card that contains the text? Your code shows the correct product name but also shows the words "Add to Cart" and "View" for the other cards.

Comment: Do you want the whole `<div class="column is-one-fifth">` to be invisible or just the parent element such as `<div class="card has-text-centered">`?

Comment: I'm trying to make `<div class="column is-one-fifth">` invisible while making the ones that contain the text collapse in its place. I've been struggling with this part for hours now since i'm not too good with javascript.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer to give you two ways of solutions.

Comment: @whitetshirt Update is done.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I really liked how you explained everything, this made me actually understand what's going on. really appreciate your help, best of luck!!

Comment: Always feels good to be appreciated! Thank you for the kind comment @whiteshirt

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JsScript is wrong when you define li variable:

- your wrong code -> li=ul.getElementsByTagName('card-content)
- the right code should be like this -> li = document.getElementsByTagName('li') or document.getElementsByClassName('card-content);

Yes, the better way for beginner is using ul with li tags. So, you would be able to focus on how the js script work on this logic. After you understand the script you can change html tag to whatever you want (must understand css style). In your JavaScript approach, you should create one ul tag and multiple li tags with innerText according to your data (this ways isn't recommended). Then you can loop through your li(s) in JavaScript like this:

```
[...li].forEach(v => v.style.display = v.includes(filter)? "" : "non");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div class="columns is-multiline" id="myUL">
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div class="card has-text-centered">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>$100</p>
        <p class="hippo">Playstation 5</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
        </p>
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div class="card has-text-centered">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>$250</p>
        <p class="hippo">Xbox</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">View</a>
        </p>
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <a href="" class="has-text-grey">Add to Cart</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        const searchValue = e.target.value;

        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".hippo")).forEach(el => {
            if (!el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                el.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
            } else {
                el.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
            }
        })
    })

</script>
</html>
```